# Clone Method not working

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to Clone a lead when certain condition is arrived using before trigger but i am not able to see cloned record.

```
 for( Lead ld : Trigger.new ) {                   
      if(ld.Integration_Source__c == 'Hubspot' && Trigger.isUpdate){
        Lead LeadBeforeUpd = Trigger.oldMap.get( ld.Id );
        if(ld.Program__c != LeadBeforeUpd.Program__c ){
           Lead ClonedLead = new Lead();
           ClonedLead = LeadBeforeUpd.clone(false, false, false, false);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not able to see cloned record"? Where are you expecting to see it? Later on in your trigger, or when you query for leads? This is either an issue of variable scope, or not inserting the clone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just creating a clone in memory. If you want to create a clone in the database, you have to save it. Remember to never do DML in a loop!

```
List<Lead> clones = new List<Lead>();
for (Lead record : trigger.new)
    clones.add(record.clone(false, false, false, false));
insert clones;
```

Also note that any time you are creating, updating, or deleting related data, you should do so in an `after` context. See [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) (emphasis mine):

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and **to affect changes in other records**, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

Comment: but as per my understanding We don't need to write DML statements....As before triggers run prior to to save operation....And i am doing cloning in Before update

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar You don't need to perform DML to execute *field updates* on the *context records*. If you want to create or modify related data, then you do need them.